# BufferError: could not get scalar buffer information

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, buffer, python-multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def parallel_apply(data, fun, args):
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() - 1)
    result = [pool.apply(fun, (data.loc[x, :], *args)) for x in data.index]
    result = [p.get() for p in result]
    end_result = pd.concat(result)
    return end_result
```

from this part of code i get following error: "BufferError: could not get scalar buffer information". I've tried several things but non of them worked. any sugesstion? thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

It would work better if your code were more complete/runnable, but from the looks of it, `data` might be a `pandas` DataFrame?

At any rate, this is likely caused by the recent release of `numpy` 1.15.0, which broke pickling of `numpy.datetime64` scalars.

`multiprocessing` uses `pickle` to serialize data between different processes.

For more details, see:

- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11656
- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/11694

An easy fix would be to downgrade to numpy 1.14.0 (or wait for 1.15.1, which should have a fix for the problem).